# Probability of an event when randomly dividing the set of items

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Are we able to easily give a probability of finding a rare item if said rare items are randomly distributed amongst other items? For example, say that we have a container full of $n$ molecules, and exactly $m$ of those molecules are of type $A$. If we put a random divider in the container so that each side of the divider has $\frac{n}{2}$ molecules, can we determine the probability that each side of the divider also contains exactly $\frac{m}{2}$ $A$ molecules?

Is that just essentially the same as if you individually pick out half of the molecules multiplying all the probabilities of picking out the different types of particles?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The probability for the even described after "for example" is given by the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution): $\binom{m}{m/2} \binom{n-m}{(n-m)/2} / \binom{n}{n/2}$. However, I don't see how this is connected to your first sentence (probability of finding a rare item).